# How do I change the password of the root user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have long since forgotten the password for the root user on one of my boxes. Is there a way I can change it without having to log in to the instance, or will I have to reinstall?

Comment: This might help "[Recover MySQL root password](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1**

Stop database:

```
shell> /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**Step 2**

Restart database

- without password autentification
- without connection to the network

Access to database is only possible through it's sock file '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'.

```
shell> mysqld --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid \
       --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/mysql \
       --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking  &
```

**Step 3**

Connect to the database and change password:

```
shell> mysql --database mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If you want to, show all users:

```
mysql> select User, password from user;
```

Set new password:

```
mysql> update user set password=password('NEW PASS') WHERE User='USERNAME';
```

Leave database connection:

```
mysql> exit
```

**Step 4**

Restart database server "normally".

```
shell> kill `cat /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid`
shell> /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick Google resulted in this answer. In the root shell type:

```
mysqladmin -u root password <password>
```

Comment: Its good to have the answer here even though it is discoverable on Google. It helps Stack Overflow become a more comprehensive repository of programming answers so I'm going to mod up this question.

Comment: This is not a very secure solution as the password is now part of your history.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Ubuntu server (possibly also Debian?) you can easily reset.

If you are on 12.04:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

If you are on 10.04:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.1
```

If you are not sure which mysql-server version is installed you can try:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server
```

See for more info:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/mysql.html