# With root access to a server, how would I change mysql root password?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the password of the root user in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482/how-do-i-change-the-password-of-the-root-user-in-mysql)

I have root access to an ec2 instance, but I don't know what the mysql root password is, which I need. How would I either 1) find this? or 2) re-install mysql and give myself a root password?

Comment: @DanielA.White you mean server fault?

Comment: It could happily live here as well, though as @sarnold correctly points out it's an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
$ /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -h localhost
> use mysql
> update user set password = password('') where user = 'root' and host='localhost';
> quit
$ sudo service mysql start
$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
```